# Excel VBA: SpecialCells copying and pasting visible cells not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that allows users to select a range and delete it, but before it deletes it copies the selected range and pastes it in another worksheet.

So far I managed to do so with a neat code I found somewhere else and edited to apply to my needs, but I found that the code does not deal well with filtered rows. I managed to delete the filtered rows only but I can't copy and paste the filtered rows.

How can I copy the filtered rows only and paste them in the last or first row of RowsDeleted sheet that starts in A4? The row count I did of the PasteSpecial gives me 8 rows when all I am trying to delete is 2 rows in a filtered range.

Right now it gives me a Paste/Range method failed.

```
'Error Handling
  If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then GoTo InvalidSelection
  If DeleteRng.Address = ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Address Then GoTo DeleteAllRows
  If ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then GoTo DeleteOnlyRow

'Ask User To confirm delete (since this cannot be undone)
    DeleteRng.Select

    If DeleteRng.Rows.Count = 1 And DeleteRng.Areas.Count = 1 Then
      Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the currently selected table row? " & _
       " This cannot be undone...", vbYesNo, "Delete Row?")
    Else
      Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the currently selected table rows? " & _
       " This cannot be undone...", vbYesNo, "Delete Rows?")
    End If

'Delete row and copy in another sheet (if wanted)
  If Answer = vbYes Then
  On Error GoTo InvalidCopySelection
  Set copyRange = DeleteRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
  Sheets("RowsDeleted").Range("A4:A4").Insert Shift:=xlDown
  Sheets("RowsDeleted").Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  DeleteRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  End If


  End If
```

Comment: Rows.count will count the rows in the ACTIVESHEET.  Is that what you want counted?  Maybe  Sheets("RowsDeleted").Cells(Sheets("RowsDeleted").Rows.Count, 1)

Comment: I don't want to count really, it was really just to test how many rows I am getting. I am trying to delete and copy/paste two rows but the test I did with count gave me 8 rows (that makes sense because I was filtering rows)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be. You know, to see the whole process of selection of the range to delete. The ** means nothing. I edited the post

Comment: You "Set copyRange",  but you don't copy the "copyRange" before you do the paste.

Comment: I am sorry for the bad code, I edited it. I had some commented code that was a bit confusing